# Keep first occurrence in one column according to certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, filter, data-mining

I'm not sure how to explain this so I'll do my best.

I have two datasets which I merged to obtain the following:

```
ID | active_date | datestamp  | code1 | code2 | code3 | payment
01 | 01/01/2020  | 10/06/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 1
01 | 01/01/2020  | 11/06/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 1
01 | 01/01/2020  | 12/06/2020 | BBB   | AAA   | .     | 2
01 | 01/01/2020  | 13/06/2020 | BBB   | AAA   | .     | 2
02 | 10/01/2020  | .          | .     | .     | .     | .
03 | 18/01/2020  | 15/05/2020 | CCC   | BBB   | AAA   | 4
03 | 18/01/2020  | 16/05/2020 | CCC   | BBB   | AAA   | 4
04 | 20/01/2020  | 24/04/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 2
04 | 20/01/2020  | 25/04/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 3
04 | 20/01/2020  | 26/04/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 3
05 | 24/01/2020  | 06/05/2020 | DDD   | .     | .     | 1
05 | 24/01/2020  | 07/05/2020 | DDD   | .     | .     | 1
```

What I need to do basically is end up with one row per ID. But with a few things to take into account:

-get the first occurrence of when code1, code2 or code3 is either "BBB" or "CCC" in either `code1`, `code2` or `code3`, or if `payment` is larger or equal than 3 .

After that it is easy to create a variable called `length` that is the difference in days between `datestamp` and `active_date`, but I need to make it so that there's only 1 row per ID with these characteristics.

The final output should look like this:

```
ID | active_date | datestamp  | code1 | code2 | code3 | payment
01 | 01/01/2020  | 12/06/2020 | BBB   | AAA   | .     | 2
02 | 10/01/2020  | .          | .     | .     | .     | .
03 | 18/01/2020  | 15/05/2020 | CCC   | BBB   | AAA   | 4
04 | 20/01/2020  | 25/04/2020 | AAA   | .     | .     | 3
05 | 24/01/2020  | 06/05/2020 | DDD   | .     | .     | 1
```

-kept the third row of `01` because there's BBB in code1.

-have to keep `02` even if it has nothing populated

-kept `03` because it's the first row with BBB and CCC in code1 and code2 for that ID

-kept the second row of `04` because it has a payment of 3, so I kept the first one.

-kept the first row of `05` because it doesn't meet the conditions, but it could be any row of `05`

I hope this makes sense. In summary, I want to group by/remove duplicates but the row I leave has to be the first occurrence if that ID meets the conditions at one point.

Tried groupby's but I can't make it work with these many conditions in different rows.

Comment: Do those dots mean `nan` or are they literal `.` strings?

Answer (score 0):

gnarly one. Compute multiple options independently and combine. Code below

```
#meets greater than equal to 3 rule
df['m']=df['payment'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float).ge(3)#create temp ro
a=df[df['m']]

#meets BBB, CCC rule

b=df[df['code1'].isin(["BBB","CCC"])|df['code2'].isin(["BBB","CCC"])|df['code3'].isin(["BBB","CCC"])].drop_duplicates(subset=['code1','code1','code1'],keep='first')

#meets unique row rule

c=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first')

#combine a,b,c and drop duplicates
df1=pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=0).drop_duplicates(subset=['code1','code1','code1'],keep='first').drop('m',1)

print(df1)

     ID active_date   datestamp code1 code2 code3 payment
5    3  18/01/2020  15/05/2020   CCC   BBB   AAA       4
8    4  20/01/2020  25/04/2020   AAA     .     .       3
2    1  01/01/2020  12/06/2020   BBB   AAA     .       2
4    2  10/01/2020           .     .     .     .       .
10   5  24/01/2020  06/05/2020   DDD     .     .       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

For convenience let's replace `.` with `nan` and convert payment datatype from `object` to `float`

```
df.replace(to_replace='.', value = np.nan, inplace = True)
df.payment = df.payment.astype(np.float)
```

Now assign column which stores True/False depending on the conditions specified.

```
cond = (df[['code1', 'code2', 'code3']].isin(['BBB', 'CCC']).any(axis = 1)
        | (df.payment >= 3))
df['cond'] = cond
```

This checks first two conditions. Now let's assign all True values to the ids where no condition is satisfied(so we choose any random row).

```
df['cond'] = cond | df.groupby('ID')['cond'].transform(lambda x: ~np.any(x))
```

Now for each ID choose first row containing True value.

```
df = (df[df['cond']].drop_duplicates(keep = 'first',  subset = ['ID', 'cond'])
      .drop(columns = ['cond']).replace(np.nan, '.'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID active_date   datestamp code1 code2 code3 payment
2    1  01/01/2020  12/06/2020   BBB   AAA     .       2
4    2  10/01/2020           .     .     .     .       .
5    3  18/01/2020  15/05/2020   CCC   BBB   AAA       4
8    4  20/01/2020  25/04/2020   AAA     .     .       3
10   5  24/01/2020  06/05/2020   DDD     .     .       1
```

You can replace NaN value with `'.'`.